# Is there a way to clear drawn shapes from a window (C++)

Tags: c++, if-statement, shapes

I would like some help to clear a drawn shape off of an open window at the press of a button, below is my code that I have tried using to clear the shape. Ideally, I would like to be able to reset the shape to its original position (after various user inputs however I had tried this idea hoping it would've been easier. Thank you in advance

```
    if (key_down(BACKSPACE_KEY))
    {
        clear_screen(COLOR_WHITE);
        delay(1500);
        fill_circle(circle_color, x, y, radius);
        refresh_screen(60);
    }
```

Comment: What is the name of the graphical library you are using? Is it SplashKit?

Comment: yes it was, I think i did manage to fix it myself by writing the following code 
        if (key_down(BACKSPACE_KEY))
        {
            x = screen_width() / 2;
            y = screen_height() / 2;
        }
This allowed me to reset the circle the position was already in